# Django: class from models.py won't import

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I have a django project where I have two models and added a third in this structure in the same file:

```
from django.db import models
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)

class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Range(models.Model):
    test = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

For brevity I've only shown the 1st line but Product and Category work perfectly.

I then added Range, went to the console and `python manage.py makemigrations`, then `python manage.py migrate`, no errors and I can see it in the migrations file.

Would somebody please put me out of my mystery and explain why in the shell:

`from products.models import Product, Category, Range`

throws

`cannot import name 'Range' from 'products.models'`

Product and Category import fine, but not Range?? Am I being dim here?

Comment: I face this issue, becuase I use different python packages  in my project, anyway, I do solve it by coping the app folder to site_package folder manually whenever new model is created in this app

Comment: Yeah, I think it's because I installed mptt. I deleted/recreated the dbs and migration files and suddenly everything works perfectly. I'm filing this under "not my fault" :)